# QML 3D basic example

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt3d

I am trying to create a basic QML application that will load a 3D model from a .obj file and display it on the screen and be able to rotate it along its axes during runtime. I went through some of the Qt examples and came up with the below code - most of which was borrowed from the working examples. But when I run it the model is not rendered properly.

The actual model looks like:

[image]

and currently my app shows up like

[image: this].

Here is the QML code -

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.12
import Qt3D.Render 2.12
import Qt3D.Extras 2.12

Entity {
    id: sceneRoot

    Camera {
        id: camera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        aspectRatio: 1820 / 1080
        nearPlane: 0.1
        farPlane: 1000.0
        position: Qt.vector3d(0.014, 0.956, 2.178)
        upVector: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.7, 0.0)
    }

    Entity {
        components: [
            DirectionalLight {
                intensity: 0.9
                worldDirection: Qt.vector3d(0, 0.6, -1)
            }
        ]
    }

    RenderSettings {
        id: external_forward_renderer
        activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
            camera: camera
            clearColor: "transparent"
        }
    }

    Mesh {
        id: roboMesh
        source: "images/robo-obj-pose4/source/d2f0cff60afc40f5afe79156ec7db657.obj"
    }

    Entity {
        id: circleEntity
        property Material roboMaterial: PhongAlphaMaterial {
            alpha: 0.4
            ambient: "black"
            diffuse: "black"
            specular: "black"
            shininess: 10000
        }

        components: [roboMesh, roboMaterial]
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Sorry for a really silly question but I am totally new to Qt3D and am confused as to what else needs to go in my code.

Comment: `obj` files do not store data related to materials or textures. They only store geometry data. References to materials for different parts of the mesh are defined in `.mtl` files. You should provide .obj, .mtl and all your texture files.

Comment: The textures (bunch of png files) are already present in the same folder path - images/robo-obj-pose4/textures . Do I need to add this path somewhere in the QML code too?
Also I do not see any .mtl files in my case. It's only obj and textures.

Comment: I am not sure if Qt3D loads the materials provided in mtl automatically. Anyway I think you should provide mtl file or define custom material entities in your qml code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a material file as suggested by the comments, you can assign generic materials the way you do it you just have some other issues with your code.

First, you need to add the `RenderSettings` as a component to the *root* entity, like so:

```
Entity {
    id: sceneRoot

    components: [external_forward_renderer]

    ...
```

Secondly, `"transparent"` is not a valid clear color. Use something like `Qt.rgba(0, 0.5, 1, 1)`.

Thirdly, you need to add `file://` to the beginning of the mesh URL, unless you have the file included in a resources file. At least I needed that prefix, maybe you don't. You can check this by having a look at the application output in QtCreator. If it says "file does not exist" then add this prefix.

If you still can't see your mesh try adding `InputSettings` (which have to be added as a component as well) and a `OrbitCameraController`:

```
InputSettings {
    id: inputSettings
}

OrbitCameraController{
    camera: camera
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your extensive reply. I made the changes as suggested but I am still getting the same output - a blank white screen.

This is how the final code looks like - https://pastebin.com/9aFtx9d6 (using pastebin due to limited characters here)

On a sidenote, I am displaying the root entity inside a Rectangle from main.qml - here is how it looks like - https://pastebin.com/ySmZ1Bxg . Should that be a problem?

Comment: OK, displaying it from inside a rectangle is probably another issue. Have a lookt at the QML example Scene 3D in QtCreator and see how they do it.

Comment: Okay, looks like I was missing a Scene3D element due to which the model was now showing up. Now I am able to display the model. The final code looks like this - https://pastebin.com/qKq18kVF

Is there a way I can resize this model while displaying to fit in its parent window or something? Currently the display is far too small. I would like to resize it dynamically, and be able to rotate it along its axes.

Comment: If my answer helped you can accept it as the solution. I'm not sure what you mean by the question in your comment. But comments are there so that people can ask you to clarify your question etc. so if you have another question go pose another :)